# Parsing Nested loops and converting to Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-structures

I have queried device information from Mongodb and the output comes as this. I need to put it in a dataframe with the following infomation:

```
 [{'message': {'obj': [{'time': '2022-06-03 00:00:00',
 'temp': 33.96,
 'humidty': 91.44,
 'x0': -543,
 'y0': 93,
 'z0': -790,
 'dmac': 'DD340206D4C6'},
{'time': '2022-06-03 00:00:00',
 'temp': 29.86,
 'humidty': 80.92,
 'x0': 178,
 'y0': 774,
 'z0': -527,
 'dmac': 'DD340206D4C6'},
{'time': '2022-06-03 00:00:00',
 'temp': 30.33,
 'humidty': 85.11,
 'x0': 94,
 'y0': -701,
 'z0': -737,
 'dmac': 'DD340206D4C6'}]}},
 {'message': {'obj': [{'time': '2022-06-03 00:00:01',
 'temp': 28.82,
 'humidty': 85.77,
 'x0': -193,
 'y0': 423,
 'z0': -820,
 'dmac': 'DD340206D4C6'},
{'time': '2022-06-03 00:00:01',
 'temp': 30.33,
 'humidty': 85.11,
 'x0': 64,
 'y0': -705,
 'z0': -744,
 'dmac': 'DD340206D4C6'},
{'time': '2022-06-03 00:00:02',
 'temp': 33.96,
 'humidty': 91.44,
 'x0': -541,
 'y0': 95,
 'z0': -798,
 'dmac': 'DD340206D4C6'}]}}
```

Expected like this:

| dmac | temp | humidity | x0 | y0 | z0 | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DD340206D4C6 | 29.86 | 91.44 | -543 | 93 | -790 | 2022-06-03 00:00:00 |

It is a dictionary of nested dictionary. Each array has contains 3 lists so i need to put each in a different row

Comment: What have you tried? We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: After making an attempt I have shared the query. I am new to stackoverflow questions so would appreciate the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data_in:

```py
in_ = [
    {
        "message": {
            "obj": [
                {
                    "time": "2022-06-03 00:00:00",
                    "temp": 33.96,
                    "humidty": 91.44,
                    "x0": -543,
                    "y0": 93,
                    "z0": -790,
                    "dmac": "DD340206D4C6"
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-06-03 00:00:00",
                    "temp": 29.86,
                    "humidty": 80.92,
                    "x0": 178,
                    "y0": 774,
                    "z0": -527,
                    "dmac": "DD340206D4C6"
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-06-03 00:00:00",
                    "temp": 30.33,
                    "humidty": 85.11,
                    "x0": 94,
                    "y0": -701,
                    "z0": -737,
                    "dmac": "DD340206D4C6"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "message": {
            "obj": [
                {
                    "time": "2022-06-03 00:00:01",
                    "temp": 28.82,
                    "humidty": 85.77,
                    "x0": -193,
                    "y0": 423,
                    "z0": -820,
                    "dmac": "DD340206D4C6"
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-06-03 00:00:01",
                    "temp": 30.33,
                    "humidty": 85.11,
                    "x0": 64,
                    "y0": -705,
                    "z0": -744,
                    "dmac": "DD340206D4C6"
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-06-03 00:00:02",
                    "temp": 33.96,
                    "humidty": 91.44,
                    "x0": -541,
                    "y0": 95,
                    "z0": -798,
                    "dmac": "DD340206D4C6"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(in_, ["message", "obj"])
df = df[["dmac", "temp", "humidty", "x0", "y0", "z0", "time"]]
```

Output:

| dmac | temp | humidty | x0 | y0 | z0 | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DD340206D4C6 | 33.96 | 91.44 | -543 | 93 | -790 | 2022-06-03 00:00:00 |
| DD340206D4C6 | 29.86 | 80.92 | 178 | 774 | -527 | 2022-06-03 00:00:00 |
| DD340206D4C6 | 30.33 | 85.11 | 94 | -701 | -737 | 2022-06-03 00:00:00 |
| DD340206D4C6 | 28.82 | 85.77 | -193 | 423 | -820 | 2022-06-03 00:00:01 |
| DD340206D4C6 | 30.33 | 85.11 | 64 | -705 | -744 | 2022-06-03 00:00:01 |
| DD340206D4C6 | 33.96 | 91.44 | -541 | 95 | -798 | 2022-06-03 00:00:02 |